# Is It possible to get 1000 images using bing search API

Tags: php, bing

I'm using **bing search image API**.

I received only 10 images from bing But I need 1000 images. Is It possible to retrieve 1000 images ?

Kindly check my code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $Key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"; // this is my api key
 $request ='http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&sources=image&query=' . urlencode( $_POST["searchText"]);
 $response = file_get_contents($request);
 $jsonobj = json_decode($response);
 echo('<ul ID="resultList">');
 foreach($jsonobj->SearchResponse->Image->Results as $value){
  echo('<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' . $value->Url . '">');
  echo('<img src="' . $value->Thumbnail->Url. '" width="150" height="150"></li>'); 
 }
 echo("</ul>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Check the documentation for a pager functionality. Might have that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html), you can use `count` and `offset` parameter to do that:

`http://api.bing.net/xml.aspx?Appid=<AppID>&query=sushi&sources=web&web.count=40&web.offset=41`

Comment: Its working fine. But in bing provide limited number of images as per my search keywords but i need 1000 images is it possible??

Comment: You can send more than 1 request and merge the results.

Comment: if you are using web based search means its working above your code.In case using image based search minimum amount of result                                         only show from bing.           http://api.bing.net/xml.aspx?Appid=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&query=sushi&sources=image&image.count=50&image.offset=51

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. For example if Bing API limit is 100 image result/request, you can get 1000 result by calling 10 requests with different `count` and `offset` parameter: `count=100&offset=1`, `count=100&offset=101`, `count=100&offset=201`, ...

Comment: Hi @TrungDQ I tried this but it can show same number of images repeately.kindly check my coding http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid=<AppID>&query=sushi&sources=image&image.count=100&image.offset=1.I change offset value it will show same images because it provide minimum amount of images For example sushi total images is 171.when reach the total count it repeats.